# Clustered Columnstore Index Update with Switch Partition

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with clustered columnstore in SQL Server 2019
Every 3 hours i recalculare few partitions and switсh it from staging table to main.

1. Are the statistics updated when I run Switch Partition? Or i need to run Update Statistics? Or what is the usual way to proceed in such a scenario?
2. Does it make sense to add an order by Date when inserting into a staging table? The question is in the context of whether the data will be sorted when inserted into the table.

Comment: For your second question, see: [How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/)

Answer (score 1):

> Does it make sense to add an order by Date when inserting into a staging table?

There's no guarantee that ORDER BY on INSERT will have any effect on the order of rows in the table.  You can use a clustered index on Date on your staging table to guarantee row ordering, which will be carried over into the CCI when you create it.